# How delete a particular object by an object array in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to delete a particular object from an object array. the array as follow

```
    data_list = [
        {
            {
                name: "george",
                age : 20,
                address: "new york"
            },
            {
                name: "mavan",
                age : 23,
                address: "new york"
            },
            {
                name: "chris",
                age : 25,
                address: "melborn"
            },
            {
                name: "jerry",
                age : 26,
                address: "dubai"
            }
        }
    ]
```

I want to delete follow object by consider the name attribute. that is `chirs`

```
{
    name: "chris",
    age : 25,
    address: "melborn"
},
```

what should I do for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data_list = data_list.filter(obj => obj.name !== 'chris')
```